# Count how many times a word has been sent by a person with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to make a bot to count how many times someone said funny and will store it in a .json file  I can get it to set up the .json and say someone said it once but it won't go any higher than 1. Thank you in advance and here is my code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!";
const token = "token";
const fs = require("fs");
Discord.Client.msg = require ("./msgs.json");

bot.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} online`);
});

bot.on("message", msg => {
    if(msg.author.bot) return;

    const say = msg.content.toLowerCase()

    if(say === "are you online?"){
        msg.reply("I am online and ready to be a funny");
    }
    if(say === "v"){
        msg.reply("is stupid @everyone");
    }
    else if (say === "funny"){

        if(![msg.author.username]){
            Discord.Client.msg [msg.author.username] = {
                funnycount: 1
            }
        }
        else{
            Discord.Client.msg [msg.author.username] = {
                funnycount: +1
            }
            msg.reply("it worked");
        }
        fs.writeFile ("./msgs.json", JSON.stringify (Discord.Client.msg, null, 4), err => {
            if (err )throw err;
        });
    }
});

bot.on("message", msg =>{
    if(!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command == "ping"){
        msg.channel.send("pong!");
    }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is the issue:

```
Discord.Client.msg [msg.author.username] = {
  funnycount: +1
}
```

`+1` does not increase the value by 1, it's just adding 1 to nothing, which will always return 1. Instead, you need to get the current value and add one. You can do this by changing your code to:

```
Discord.Client.msg [msg.author.username] = {
  funnycount: Discord.Client.msg[msg.author.username].funnycount++
}
```

Using `++` increases the value by 1.

Comment: I forgot to add Discord.Client.msg for it to check
```if(!Discord.Client.msg[msg.author.username]){
            Discord.Client.msg [msg.author.username] = {
                nwordcount: 1
            }```